# Checking whether nested variable is defined in the when statement

Tags: ansible

Nested data structures can be accessed either by indexing using the key name or dot syntax with the key name - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-complex-variable-data

But I'm not able to access nested data structure from variables in the when statement. Here is a minimal sample to demonstrate the issue

```
# cat play.yml                                                                                                         
- hosts: localhost   
  vars:
    parent:
      child1: true   tasks:
  - name: "Check if variable is defined"
    fail:
      msg: "mandatory variable {{ item }} not passed as extra args when invoking playbook"
    when: item not in vars
    loop:
    - parent
    - parent.child1
    - parent.child2
```

Here is the sample output

```
ansible-playbook play.yml                                                                                             (livingstone-dev/monitoring)
 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Check if variable is defined] **************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=parent) 
failed: [localhost] (item=parent.child1) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "parent.child1", "msg": "mandatory variable parent.child1 not passed as extra args when invoking playbook"}
failed: [localhost] (item=parent.child2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "parent.child2", "msg": "mandatory variable parent.child2 not passed as extra args when invoking playbook"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Any idea how I can have nested variables in ansible when statements. Here are some things which I've already tried and didn't work:

1. Using dotted notation for accessing variable
2. Changing the when statement to "item is not defined" without the quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working playbook. Thanks to @smily for pointing me in the right direction. Since the loop variable item needs to be evaluated before the when condition is evaluated, I had to expand the variable item. I've done it by encompassing the entire when condition in double quotes and just expanding the item loop variable.

```
$ cat play.yml                                                                                                          (livingstone-dev/monitoring)
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    parent:
      child1: true
  tasks:
  - name: show variable
    debug:
      var: parent
  - name: "Check if variable is defined"
    fail:
      msg: "mandatory variable item not passed as extra args when invoking playbook"
    when: "{{item}} is not defined"
    loop:
    - parent
    - parent.child1
    - parent.child2
```

Here is the playbook output.

```
$ ansible-playbook play.yml                                                                                             (livingstone-dev/monitoring)
 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'


PLAY [localhost] *********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [show variable] *****************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "parent": {
        "child1": true
    }
}

TASK [Check if variable is defined] **************************************************************************************************************************
 [WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: {{item}} is not defined

skipping: [localhost] => (item=parent) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=parent.child1) 
failed: [localhost] (item=parent.child2) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "parent.child2", "msg": "mandatory variable item not passed as extra args when invoking playbook"}

PLAY RECAP ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code worked for me. You have to provide the values in loop within `"{{}}"`

```
  -  name: "Check if variable is defined"
     fail:
      msg: "mandatory variable {{ item }} not passed as extra args when invoking playbook"
     loop:
      - "{{parent.child1}}"
      - "{{parent}}"
      - "{{parent.child2}}"
     when: item is not defined
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It does work but doesn't give the relevant error message. The entire task fails without even executing the loop with the following error message: {"msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'child2'"}. But it did help me arrive at the solution though. Thanks. I will post it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same result without warning change

```
when: "{{item}} is not defined"
```

to

```
when: not vars|json_query(item)
```

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Getting this error for all loop items.
`"msg": "Invalid options for fail: when"`
Does it work for you? Am I missing something here?

Comment: I've fixed the condition.